# PostGIS two "circles" intersection

Tags: postgis

I am trying to see if two "circles" intersect. The data I have is  two points and two radii (in meters). I am using srid 4326.  My main issue (i think) is getting the radius in meters.

```
SELECT (ST_Buffer('POINT (-104.949517 39.740264)',300) && 
          ST_Buffer('POINT (-104.999924 35.000089)',300))
```

My questions are

1. Is there a more clever way to do this?
2. Or how do I convert the radius from dd to meters to get correct buffers?

Comment: Calculate the distance between the 2 points. Is it smaller than the total length of the radii?

Comment: would that be the same as using ST_Dwithin ?

Comment: Is there any chance to repoen this question ? I am looking for the exact same thing and can't find how to do it, even with the duplicate question link (I am a SQL noob).